# nping ipv6 error on sending tcp packets

Tags: networking, ping, ipv6, tcp

I am pinging websites using nping through tcp. I am using JIO. So it can even process ipv6 addresses. When pinging ipv4 addresses,it works great. But for IPv6, the packet which was sent gets lost. I read the man nping and made request according to that.

Here it is for ipv4:

```
paulsteven@smackcoders:~$ sudo nping -c 1 -p 80 --tcp www.google.com

Starting Nping 0.7.01 ( https://nmap.org/nping ) at 2019-03-06 13:01 IST
SENT (0.2184s) TCP 192.168.43.213:47110 > 172.217.31.196:80 S ttl=64 id=29192 iplen=40  seq=2372108032 win=1480 
RCVD (0.4047s) TCP 172.217.31.196:80 > 192.168.43.213:47110 SA ttl=119 id=2005 iplen=44  seq=1784572716 win=60720 <mss 1370>

Max rtt: 186.254ms | Min rtt: 186.254ms | Avg rtt: 186.254ms
Raw packets sent: 1 (40B) | Rcvd: 1 (44B) | Lost: 0 (0.00%)
Nping done: 1 IP address pinged in 1.27 seconds
```

For IPv6:

```
paulsteven@smackcoders:~$ sudo nping -6 -c 1 -p 80 --tcp www.google.com

Starting Nping 0.7.01 ( https://nmap.org/nping ) at 2019-03-06 13:01 IST
SENT (0.4590s) TCP :::1186 > 2404:6800:4007:807::2004:80 S seq=2415561998 win=1480 

Max rtt: N/A | Min rtt: N/A | Avg rtt: N/A
Raw packets sent: 1 (20B) | Rcvd: 0 (0B) | Lost: 1 (100.00%)
Nping done: 1 IP address pinged in 1.49 seconds
```

Comment: Do you have global IPv6 connectivity?

Comment: Yes. I can access IPv6 websites.

Comment: According to the output it is using `::` as source address. That is never going to work. Why it is using that source address is the big mystery.

Comment: Is there any other ping software which sends TCP packets for IPv6. I searched on Google and i found this nping only. Anyother TCP ping software available???